# Concat 2 columns based on ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, concatenation, ssms

I am trying to merge 2 columns based on same ID but having an issue where a null value in any of the 2 columns make the result null

Data looks like this

```
 ID  Notes      Date
-----------------------
 1   notes1     3/1/20
 1   notes2     3/2/20
 1   notes3     3/3/20
 2   notes1
 2   notes2
```

Desired Output

```
Id    CombinedNotes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Date: 3/1/20 Notes: Notes1 Date: 3/2/20 Notes: Notes2 Date: 3/3/20 Notes: Notes3
2     Date: NUll Notes: Notes1 Date: Null Notes: Notes2
```

Actual current output is:

```
Id    CombinedNotes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Date: 3/1/20 Notes: Notes1 Date: 3/2/20 Notes: Notes2 Date: 3/3/20 Notes: Notes3
2     Null
```

I am running this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.[id],
    STUFF ((SELECT ' Date: ' + t1.[date] + ' Notes:' + [notes]   
            FROM [dbo].[test1] t1
            WHERE t1.[id] = t2.[id]
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM
    [dbo].[test1] t2
```

The result looks like this :

[image]

What should I change and also is it possible to not have 'Date:' like this when it's blank so desired output will look like this

```
 2        Notes: Notes1 Notes: Notes2
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: The [function `CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is smarter than simple `+` concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

`{Some string} + {NULL Value} = NULL` That's the problem. As you have `' Date: '  + t1.[date] + ' Notes:' + [notes]` this translates to `' Date:' + '3/1/20' + 'Notes:' + NULL` which returns `NULL`.

Use `ISNULL` (or `COALESCE`) to return the literal value `'NULL'`:

```
' Date: '  + t1.[date] + ' Notes:' + ISNULL([notes],'NULL')
```

*Side note: Also, because you are wrapping `t1.[date]` in a `CONVERT`/`CAST` this **strongly** implies that `[date]` is not a `date` but a `varchar`. You really should be fixing your data type there. Store dates in date (and time) data type. `varchar` is **not** a "one size fits all" data type.*

*Plus you have the problem that the value is something like `'3/1/20'` What date is that? 3 January 2020? 1 March 1920? 20 January 2003? The list goes on. That column **needs** fixing.*

Comment: Thank you and same can be applied if date is null and notes are not null right?

Comment: Correct, @gauravk . The real take home here though is **fix** the data type of your column `date`.

Comment: Thank you Larnu for your help and suggestion. In the actual database everything is in the right format but I just wanted to see how I can get this step right.

Comment: *"everything is in the right format"*, if that is the case, @gauravk, then the above would return the error along the lines of "cannot correct varchar value ' Date: ' to date. The fact that you aren't getting that error is evidence enough that `[date]` is not a `date`.

Comment: I did get the errors but It's fixed now and it worked. Thank you.